# Setting up distributed MongoDB with 4 servers

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am supposed to setup mongodb on 4 servers (a school project to benchmark mongodb, vs others). So I am thinking of using only sharding without replication. So I attempted to setup the 1st 3 server to run `mongod --configsvr`, and the 4th just a normal `mongod` instance. Then for all servers, I run `mongos`. Then I am at the part where I run `sh.addShard("...")` and I get

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "the specified mongod is a --configsvr and should thus not be a shard server"
}
```

Seems like I cant have a config server running as a shard too? How then should I set things up?

Answer (score 0):

No, the config server is **not** a shard. The [config server](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-config-servers/) is a special mongod instance that stores the sharded cluster metadata, essentially how the data is distributed across the sharded cluster.

You really only need 1 mongos instance for a simple setup like this. When you start mongos, you will provide it with the hostname(s) of your config server(s).

The [Sharded Cluster Deployment Tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/) explains all of the steps that you need to follow.